# Regarding oppressed people

Tags: dua

Is it true that an oppressed persons prayers are answered quickly by Allah and we should avoid oppressing people. I want a detailed answer as much as possible for this question.

Comment: This question asks generally about oppressed and tortured peoples supplication. I need it for personal reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a saheeh hadeeth that states this

> "The Messenger of Allah sent Mu'adh [bin Jabal] to Yemen, and said:
> 'Beware of the supplication of the oppressed; for indeed there is no
> barrier between it and Allah.'" [Tirmidhi 2014](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2014)

Answer (score 0):

In Mustadrak it is mentioned Oh Muslims take refuge from prayer of oppressed as it goes to sky like spark in fire. It is also clear from Hadees prayers of ill people are very very close to Allah.

But you should be more worried when you are doing wrong with an oppressed person. If you haven't done anything wrong and oppression is done by someone else then it is not your fault. And also keep in mind every oppressed looking person might not be oppressed.